# Print out the total of the last 10 numbers in array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java and I can not for the life of me figure out how to solve this question. I'm assuming the problem has something to do with everything including and after the for(int i = 0; i <= amount; i++){ line and I can't think of what I'm doing wrong. I was wondering if my code is at least close to a working solution? Any help would be appreciated.

Question: Write Java code that allows a user to repeatedly enter numbers. Each time the user enters a number, the program should print out the total of the last 10 numbers (or all numbers if 10 or less have been entered).

The way I did it, the program stops if the user enters a negative number.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbersList = new int[10];
    int number = in.nextInt();
    int amount = 0;
    int total = 0;
    while(number>=0){ //stop at negative
        number = in.nextInt();
        amount += 1;
        for(int i = 0; i <= amount; i++){
            numbersList[i] = number;
            for(int j = 0; j < numbersList.length; j++){
                total += numbersList[j];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

I'm working on trying to get the program to correctly print the last 10 numbers of the array, but it for some reason prints a total much higher than it should be.

Input example:

1

2

3

4

-1

Output:

84

It prints out 84 when the correct answer should be 10.

Comment: Wait, what is the purpose of your first for loop, it's assigning every index in your array to the most recent input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first for loop is assigning every index in your array to the most recent input. You should not need a nested for-loop to complete this assignment. Here's an example with comments that explain different aspects of the code.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] numbersList = new int[10];
int amount = 0;
int total = 0;

do { //stop at negative
    int number = in.nextInt();
    if (number < 0) {
        // if a negative number is entered then stop looping
        break;
    }

    amount += 1;

    // use modulo arithmetic to assign numbers, the accessed index will
    // range from 0 to 9
    numbersList[amount % 10] = number;

    // iterate over numbersList and sum entries
    for(int i = 0; i < numbersList.length; i++){
        total += numbersList[i];
    }

    // output total
    System.out.println(total);

    // reset total to 0
    total = 0;
} while(number >= 0); // this is redundant since we check earlier

System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Just declare `number` as `int number;`, it will automatically take the value 0. No need to ask the Scanner. This first int would never be used since you ask for another in the while-loop.
2. In round n you are replacing your first n+1 integers (0 <= i <= n -> n+1 rounds; use `i < amount` instead) with the number of the current round. This will lead to an Exception, if you "play" more than 9 rounds.
3. After every replacement of a single integer, you over the complete Array. Notice, that this total is never reset.
4. You are not stopping directly after the input of a negative number, rather than also running a round with this negative number and then terminating. So use a `break;` if you find out, that `number` is negative (so test this after you got it from the scanner).

Thus you take the overall sum over following arrays (trailing 0s omitted):

```
[2] //2
[2,2] //2 + 2 + 2 = 6
[3,2] //6 + 3 + 2 = 11
[3,3] // 11 + 3 + 3 = 17
[3,3,3] // 17 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 26
[4,3,3] // 26 + 4 + 3 + 3 = 36
[4,4,3] // 36 + 4 + 4 + 3 = 47
[4,4,4] // 47 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 59
[4,4,4,4] // 59 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 75
[-1,4,4,4] // 75 - 1 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 86
[-1,-1,4,4] // 86 - 1 - 1 + 4 + 4 = 92
[-1,-1,-1,4] // 92 - 1 - 1 - 1 + 4 = 93
[-1,-1,-1,-1] // 91 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 = 89
[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1] // 89 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 = 84
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works too.

```
        ArrayList<Integer> numbersList = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = in.nextInt();
        int total = 0;
        while (number>=0) { //stop at negative
        //store all numbers in ArrayList
        numbersList.add(number);
        //for the first 10 numbers we can just add them as follows
        if(numbersList.size()<=10) {
                total += number;
                System.out.println(total);
        }
        //if user imputs more than 10 numbers we need to count the total of the last 10 numbers so:
        else
        {
                //Restore total to 0 for recount
                total =0;
                //iterate Arraylist backwards for the last 10 values inputed in it
        for(int j = 10; j >=1  ; j--) {
                total += numbersList.get(numbersList.size()-j);
        }
                System.out.println(total);
        }
        //get next number
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        number = in.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(total);
```